# MP4 moof fragment headers

Tags: video, ffmpeg, mp4, h.264, mp4box

I have a MP4 parser software that get's a fragmented `.mp4` video, parses the `MOOV` and fragment headers and streams it. I have generated a `.mp4` file myself using `FFMPEG` and `MP4Box`/`bento4`, but the software has problems processing it.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -g 25 -c:v libx264 -c:a copy out1.mp4

mp4fragment out1.mp4 --fragment-duration 1000 --track 'video' output.mp4
```

Using the `MP4 Explorer` software, I noticed in my generated `.mp4` file, for all `moof.traf.trun`, sample duration is set to **0**, but in the Track Fragment Header box, it sets the `default_sample_duration` to 512. While in the another `.mp4` file which works fine, there is no `default_sample_duration` field, but each individual sample has a duration of size 512. Looks like this might cause the problem. The right figure shows the working mp4, and the left one is my generated mp4.

Is this an update in the newer versions of `FFMPEG` (or `MP4Box` or `bento4`)? Is there any ways to force setting the sample duration in samples?

[My .mp4 file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jh89ymivznzzryv/final_v.mp4?dl=0)

[The working .mp4 file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yds8wcrp2qqd7a7/edv_g24.mp4?dl=0)

[image]

Comment: This looks like a `mp4box` issue, since it's creating the `MOOF` boxes. Share your mp4box command.

Comment: Are you sure that 0x000100 sample-duration-present flag is actually set? - May be your viewer may default to zero.

Comment: @MarkusSchumann yes that is what I was thinking about. Probably there is no field that the processing software `segmentation faults`. Do you know how I can check this?

Comment: @Mulvya I actually used bento4 to fragment and save video only track:  `bento4 --fragment-duration 1000 --track 'video' output.mp4`

Comment: Can you share the file(s)?

Comment: @MarkusSchumann I updated the question with the links

Comment: final_v.mp4 has not set the duration flag. Your viewer is misleading by displaying the duration as '0' - it is simple not set which is correctly flagged in trun.flags (0x100 is not set). Just looking at trun.entry[].duration - final_v.mp4 is correctly authored. Your file is likely not playing for some other reason.

Comment: So maybe the processing software assumes this field exists, and wants to get the data value, but doesn't find it. Right?

Comment: @MarkusSchumann How can we access the `default sample duration` field in the fragment header?

Comment: What software are you using for playback (or processing)? Do you have the source? Can you debug it?Using the default length makes more sense since it  is more space efficient.

Comment: It is a huge base on proprietary code. But I just need a C++ function that returns the value of `default_sample_duration` given a file name! I couldn't find anything online.

Comment: @MarkusSchumann Hi Markus, I can share the source with you. But let's have a private chat. It should be easy for a C++ guy.

Comment: @MarkusSchumann I couldn't find your email. But please let me know how to get in touch.

Comment: go4shoe at hotmail com

Comment: @MarkusSchumann ok sent u a message.

Comment: I use http://www.onlinemp4parser.com/ for parsing my MP4 files. It gives lot more details than MP4 Explorer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. parse the TFHD
2. extract the default_sample_duration
3. use the default_sample_duration instead of the absent duration from TRUN